# Capistrano cap production deploy:initial Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I am following this tutorial for setting up a webserver for a simple rails app: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma with nginx and capistrano.

my deploy.rb file:

```
# Change these
server '45.33.11.11', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git@bitbucket.org:slucha/supplement.git'
set :application,     'supplementtests'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

and Capfile

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require "capistrano/scm/git"



# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git
```

Nginx is installed, ssh keys are set up for both  bitbucket ssh and deploy keys for the repo and rvm ist also installed on the server

The `cap staging deploy:check` command passes without errors but when I try to run `cap production deploy:initial` I get the following error

```
** Invoke production (first_time)
** Execute production
** Invoke load:defaults (first_time)
** Execute load:defaults
** Invoke bundler:map_bins (first_time)
** Execute bundler:map_bins
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_rails_env
** Invoke deploy:set_linked_dirs (first_time)
** Execute deploy:set_linked_dirs
** Invoke deploy:set_rails_env 
** Invoke rvm:hook (first_time)
** Execute rvm:hook
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as root@45.79.147.60: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout: Net::SSH::ConnectionTimeout
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:90:in `rescue in initialize'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:57:in `initialize'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for 45.79.147.60:22
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:65:in `connect'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:65:in `connect_internal'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:140:in `connect'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:338:in `block in tcp'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `each'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:232:in `foreach'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb:328:in `tcp'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `new'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-4.2.0/lib/net/ssh.rb:237:in `start'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `call'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/connection_pool.rb:59:in `with'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:176:in `with_ssh'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:129:in `execute_command'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `tap'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:141:in `create_command_and_execute'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:55:in `test'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/capistrano-rvm-0.1.2/lib/capistrano/tasks/rvm.rake:21:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `instance_exec'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:29:in `run'
/home/jan/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sshkit-1.15.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
Tasks: TOP => rvm:hook
```

Any ideas why there is a timeout?

UPDATE

ssh -T git@bitbucket.org gives message:

```
logged in as slucha.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

ssh -T deploy@45.33.95.53 gives

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.64-x86_64-linode88 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

Comment: Your server is specified as `45.33.11.11`, but the SSH is timing out from `45.79.147.60`. Are you certain that your server IP is correct in the deploy file? Did you set up your SSH key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to work with your server?

Comment: Yes sorry, I just put these 1s in as a placeholder

Comment: Try running the deploy command directly, outside of Capistrano. If it works, your SSH key is not being referenced correctly  by Cap, verify the set up. If it does not work, then something is wrong with the SSH key altogether. Cannot guide you further without any additional debug information.

Comment: ssh -T git@bitbucket.org and ssh and both ssh -T deploy@45.33.95.53 give me successful responses so I guess the ssh keys are fine. I updated the above question with the feedback for the ssh requests.

Comment: @ArmanH what do you mean by running the deploy command directly? It is a capistrano specific command...

Comment: I meant to try doing a `git push` to the server directly, which Capistrano does under the hood for you.

Comment: I think Capistrano pushes from bitbucket to server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had two conflicting settings between the deploy.rb and production.rb

make sure that your settings in both files are correct.
in my production.rb I had the following line:

```
server '53.33.95.53', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{web app}
```

Which was overwriting the current ip address and was causing the timeout.